# R newbie- is there a way to separate or filter out items listed in a single cell for plotting purposes?

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Problem**

R and stack overflow newbie here so try and be patient with me. I am currently working on a `data.frame` that will act as a summary of various modeling approaches used to predict either fall events or fall rates within an in-patient setting based on a range of hospital, environmental and individual-level variables.

My data is in long format and some studies have several rows (I have created a row for each model type, with some studies having built multiple). For some columns (i.e., Model performance) I have multiple entries separated by a comma (e.g., C-statistic, Hosmer-Lemeshow test, likelihood ratio, and so forth). My question is, is there a way to separate these so I can create a barplot in ggplot2 that shows the prevalence of different methods and there is one bar per statistic/test type, with the height of the bar being a count of the number of instances in the data frame it occurs? At the moment this obviously does not work as some bars have a label that contains all of the values (i.e, C-statistic, Hosmer-Lemeshow test, likelihood ratio), which means there can be multiple bars that contain "c-statistic" for example, because the list is slightly different.

**Screenshots and code**

I have attached a screenshot of my `data.frame` below. The column I refer to is "Statistic.reported"

Screenshot of datadrame:

[image]

I have also attached an image of what happens when I create a basic `barplot` with the following code:

`Bar <- ggplot(Modelling.Data, aes(x=Statistic.reported)) +geom_bar()+ theme_classic()`

Image of plot using current basic code:~

[image]

**Things I have tried**
I have tried using the `tidyr` package function seperate_rows my code for this was as follows
`separate_rows(Modelling.Data,Modelling.Data$Statistic.reported, sep = ",")`
From this I got an error that said "Can't subset columns that don't exist".

Hopefully, this makes sense, but I'm really new to all of this so if you need anything else please tell me. Any tips or advice would be hugely appreciated! Apologies in advance for my complete lack of knowledge.

Comment: As a small note, it should be `separate_rows(Modelling.Data, Statistic.reported, sep = ",")` because tidyverse uses non-standard evaluation (NSE), so you type the column name as a symbol instead of `$`-subsetting.

Comment: Hi L.Greig. Try to give us a reproducible set. dput(head(Modelling.Data)) should output a structure you can paste in your question.
That said, try `separate_rows(Modelling.Data, Statistic.reported, sep = ",")` .

Comment: Hi @NicolásVelásquez What do you mean by a reproducible set? I know i'm probably being a pain here and i'm sure anyone reading is going to roll their eyes as they mutter "rookie". But, as a rule of thumb, what are the key ingredients in making it reproducible? I want to make sure in the future that I am as transparent as possible.

Comment: Also thank you both! The modified code you suggested worked a treat

Comment: We cannot copy data from an image.Hence we need data in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Hi @L.Greig_97. No worries, this is a place where we all learn from each other.
A reproducible set or example in your case could be a sample of your data frame that we can replicate in our machines.
At any rate, `dput()` is an R function that generates a replicable data structure that you can paste in your question. It is very handy to obtain reproducible sets.